# count unique text values based on condition in another column between date criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

What i need  is formula to count unique values in TITLE based on criteria of column FIAP/Medium & Year.

This needs to begin by looking at the date in worksheet column M/Year, the range is **23/03/13 - 01/06/16**.  It then needs to check column I/FIAP Medium looking for **'Digital**' and finally count the unique images in A/Title.

This is the working sheet column

```
   Title              FIAP/Medium      Year
  Conors Push        Digital         3/23/2013
  Conors Push        Digital         4/1/2013
  Flippin Hell       Digital         4/1/2013
 Narrowing the Gap   Digital         4/1/2013
 The Perfect Storm   Digital         4/8/2013
 Conors Push         Digital         4/12/2013
 Splash and Dash     Digital         4/12/2013
 Wind Power          Digital         4/12/2013
 Conors Push           -             4/28/2013
 Eyes On The Ball      -             4/28/2013
 Narrowing the Gap     -             4/28/2013
 The Bunkers Demise    -             4/28/2013
 A Few Inches More   Digital         5/1/2013
 Entwined            Digital         5/1/2013
 Conors Push         Digital         5/14/2013
 Fosbury Delight     Digital         5/14/2013
 Narrowing The Gap   Digital         5/14/2013
 Sprint For The Lin  Digital         5/14/2013
```

I have come up with formula

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(International!M2:M1000>="6/1/2016",IF(International!M2:M1000<="3/23/2013",IF(International!I2:I1000<>"",IF(International!I2:I1000="Digital",MATCH(International!A2:A1000,International!A2:A1000,0))))),ROW(International!A2:A1000)-ROW(International!A2)+1>0)))
```

but its showing zero value. It may be because date condition requires two condition with one column.

Please help me with this formula or any other method to count unique based on this conditions.**Specially dates**

Comment: Are there constant additions/deletions to the list? Would you have to modify the formula constantly ad change the ranges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a fairly common method of a pseudo-COUNTUNIQUE¹ based on the [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) and [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) functions that looks like this.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:A19, A2:A19&""))
```

But that does compensate for the conditions. To add conditions, you need to change to a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED). Additionally, both the numerator and denominator of the division operation have to be adjusted by the conditions and the inverse of the conditions in order that you return a true count without erroring on with a `#DIV/0!`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((C$2:C$19>=F2)*(C$2:C$19<=G2)*($B$2:$B$19=E2))/
             (COUNTIFS(A$2:A$19, A$2:A$19&"", C$2:C$19, ">="&F2, C$2:C$19, "<="&G2, $B$2:$B$19, E2)+
              (C$2:C$19<F2)+(C$2:C$19>G2)+($B$2:$B$19<>E2)))
```

[image: count_unique_with_conditions]

Now that formula is hard to maintain of there are constant additions and deletions to the number of rows. To create dynamic ranges, we can [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) each full column and use [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to locate the last date as the terminator for each column.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))>=F2)*(C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))<=G2)*($B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))=E2))/
    (COUNTIFS(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,C:C )), A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))&"", C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,C:C )), ">="&F2, C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,C:C )), "<="&G2, B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,C:C )), E2)+
      (C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))<F2)+(C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))>G2)+($B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))<>E2)))
```

Yes, that looks like a mess but it dynamically adds and subtracts rows processed by the SUMPRODUCT function so that calculation efficiency is at a premium.

---

¹ <sub>For an explanation on how this works see [Count Unique with SUMPRODUCT() Breakdown](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2003-excel/count-unique-with-sumproduct-breakdown/1bc18979-4172-4537-993e-3897f74d6a5b).</sub>

Comment: It really only **looks** complex because of the repetitious MATCH functions that are need to truncate the full column references at the row containing the last date. SUMPRODUCT should never be used with full column references unless you are getting paid by the calculation cycle. 1,000 or even 25,000 rows may seem like a lot but both are a lot less than 1,048,576 rows. The formula can be simplified with a dynamic named range but that would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

You formula works with a few tweaks:

1. The date strings need to be converted to date values using DateValue() function
2. The comparison operators for the dates are interchanged (it should be <= 2016 date and >= 2013 date)
3. The comparison against "digital" needs to be reversed
4. The innermost IF statement needs a zero as value for situations where the condition fails
5. I removed the outermost parentheses which are not needed

Here is the modified version that works:

=FREQUENCY(IF(International!M2:M1000<=DATEVALUE("6/1/2016"),IF(International!M2:M1000>=DATEVALUE("3/23/2013"),IF(International!I2:I1000<>"",IF(International!I2:I1000<>"Digital",MATCH(International!A2:A1000,International!A2:A1000,0),0)))),ROW(International!A2:A1000)-ROW(International!A2)+1>0)

Comment: What should the correct answer be? I set up the worksheet as you showed in the question and the formula works; I tested by changing some of the values and saw the count change appropriately. It is possible there are aspects you've not mentioned that are impacting the solution. At any rate, if answer from @Jeeped works for you, you're good anyway.