# How many different values appear in an Excel column?

Tags: excel

I have a column of repeated texts (companies) mapped to a column on whether a condition was met.

How do I count how many companies met the condition? For example the picture below should yield 2 (counting 1 for "Google" + 1 for "Apple" and 0 for "Sun")

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($B$2:$B$11="Y",1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A$2:$A$11,$B$2:$B$11,"Y")))
```

[image]

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: Thanks! that worked! Is it possible to use a similar method if i count the company only if it belongs to a certain group, for example Google belongs to Group A and Apple and Sun to group B? I tried adding another criteria to the if but it gave me a div/0 error.
=SUM(IF($J$6:$J$167="Y",1/COUNTIFS($F$6:$F$167,$F$6:$F$167,$J$6:$J$167,"Y", $B$6:$B$167, "Y")))

Comment: @Matteo - See my response to [count unique text values based on condition in another column between date criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103284/count-unique-text-values-based-on-condition-in-another-column-between-date-crite/36104062#36104062).

Comment: You need to add the second criteria to the first part of the IF also.  But that is a new question.  This one has been answered.